# Convergence of a sequence $\frac{1}{1+n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How can I prove by integral test that the sequence $1+ \dfrac{1}{1+2^3} + \dfrac{1}{1+3^3} + \dots + \dfrac{1}{1+n^3}$ is convergent?

Thank you. Is there a way that I can integrate $\dfrac{1}{1+n^3}$ ?

Comment: The integral of $1/(1 + t^3)$ can be computed using WolframAlpha (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+1%2F%281+%2B+x%5E3%29)).  (Just replace the dummy variable $x$ with $t$ everywhere it occurs. =] )

Comment: Have you tried $u=t^2-t+1$ as a substitution?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the first sentence of your question.  It would be easier just to ask if the associated infinite series converges.  Do you _have_ to use the integral test?  It would be easier to use the comparison test (you don't even need the limit comparison test).  That doesn't answer your question, but this is just a comment.

Comment: Integrate or Sum ?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case somebody doesn't feel like doing calculus today:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^3} < \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n^3-n} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(n)(n-1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n)}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2(2-1)} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

I will guess that the $n$-th term of the sequence is
$$\frac{1}{1+1^3}+\frac{1}{1+2^3}+\frac{1}{1+3^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1+n^3}.$$

There is indeed a closed form for $\int \frac{1}{1+t^3}\,dt$. However, the details are somewhat unpleasant. It is simpler to note that the $n$-th term is less than $\frac {1}{1^3}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n^3}$
and use the fact that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^3}\,dt$ converges.

Alternately, we can use the fact that the $n$-th term is less than or equal to 
$$\frac{1}{1+1^2}+\frac{1}{1+2^2}+\frac{1}{1+3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1+n^2},$$
and use the fact that $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt$ converges.